# Removing full screen button for embedded youtube video in Android

Tags: android, button, youtube, fullscreen

I'm embedding a youtube video in Android app. All is going fine:

frameWebview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
                + Util.getYoutubeVideoId(artist.getVideoLinks().get(iterator)) + "?fs=0");

The issue is i don't want full screen button appears. I have set fs=0 but it doesn't goes. Any idea?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the full-screen in embed video from youtube, better consider using youtube API. Refer this post [Is it possible to disable full screen for youtube api in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429928/is-it-possible-to-disable-full-screen-for-youtube-api-in-android)

Comment: Thanks. The issue is button appears but full screen is not going. Full screen it's not a requirement for me so we can hide full screen button if it's possible and it will solve it. My question it not if full screen is disaleable, is if button is hideable. Regards.

Comment: Hi @Joterito, did you solve this issue? I have the same with you. Please give me a suggestion. Thanks :)